# Importing a large project into Eclipse (SVN, Maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, maven, proxy

I just started interning for a CIS team at a large company, and I'm trying to get my workspace set up. Right now I have to import the cis project from the SVN repository into Eclipse. The problem is that the project is huge (multi moduled with many revisions), and when I try to check out the entire project it gets to 95% and goes into a gruelingly slow crawl as it starts checking out all of the revisions.

So I read the Eclipse install instructions on my department's wiki page, and it tells me that I need to export a Team Project Set by doing

```
Export -> Team Project Set
```

on my "old" Eclipse and then later importing the .psf that I acquire out of the export onto the "new" Eclipse

But this is not available to me as I'm on a newly formatted computer and I have no previous projects to export.

I can import a small portion of the project that I can work with, but I can't seem to find the JAR files that I need for the build path.

I've spent almost 3 days on this, and I'm startting to pull out my hair. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Ask your supervisor or mentor to create this file for you.  The whole idea is to reuse an existing setup.

Comment: I definitely would ask my supervisor but he's on a business trip this whole week. I will try asking one of the other senior members to help me with that though.

Comment: **Anyone with those projects in the workspace can generate a Team Project Set for you.** BTW, it's a bit unusual that you need it at all given you're using Maven.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's going on with Maven in my case. I know we have a Maven repository that we deploy into, but I was not given an address for the SCM nor was I told that I need to retrieve anything from Maven at the moment. One of the guys said that I don't need a Team Project Set because I'm not migrating anything.

Comment: OK, I've just re-read your post and noticed what the blocking problem is. Well, a TPS is just a simple XML-based configuration container for SCM URLs - it certainly won't making the process of checking out the codebase any faster.

Comment: I see. Interesting. In any case, I did find a work-around. I will post the answer when StackOverflow will allow me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some experimenting I found a solution which seems to work for now. I ended up importing solely from the directory that had all the files of code necessary for the scope of my first task.

However, I ran into a problem that I had been having before where I couldn't use basic navigation commands like F3 for viewing declarations. To fix this I did:

```
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source Tab
```

The only folder on the build path was `cis/src`. I removed this one and added the entire parent directory `cis`.

If you are importing from an SVN repository and you can't change the settings for the build path, make sure that you imported your project as a JAVA Project, as opposed to a general project. This should link whatever JAR files you need.

If you need to add another folder/directory from the SVN that you didn't import initially, you can do so by doing almost the same steps as you did the first time:

```
File -> Import -> Project from SVN -> choose the appropriate directory ->
Select "Check out as a folder into existing project" in "Check Out As" window.
```

Afterwards you can move the newly imported files as necessary.

Fellow interns, if you aren't sure about *anything*, DO NOT hesitate to ask your supervisors for help and clarification.